# Incorrect argument type for function 'JSENCODE()'

Tags: apex, javascript

I have ran my visualforce page in varacode scan and got one High flaw in script. To fix that I have used JSENCODE() but getting the below error.

```
Error : Incorrect argument type for function 'JSENCODE()'. 

Flaw in varacode scan : 
-----------------------
Improper Neutralization of Script-Related HTML Tags in a Web Page (Basic XSS) (CWE ID 80)

Script line in visualforce page : 
---------------------------------
var strAutoCompleteUsers = '{!lstUsersAutoComplete}'.replace('[','');

This is a list variable from Controller :
------------------------------------------
public List<User> lstUsersAutoComplete {get;set;}

Applied JSENCODE() :
--------------------
var strAutoCompleteUsers = '{!JSENCODE(lstUsersAutoComplete)}'.replace('[','');
```

Any help here how to fix the flaw

Answer (score 0):

You can't use JSENCODE on anything other than a `String`. The easiest solution would be to use `JSON.serialize` to encode the data safely.

```
// Apex
public String getUserListJSON() {
  return JSON.serialize(lstUsersAutoComplete);
}
```

```
// JavaScript
var lstUsersAutoComplete = {!userListJSON};
```

Note that there are not quotes around `{!userListJSON}` intentionally. The JSON string, which is guaranteed to be safe, is inserted directly into the script as code to be parsed in the script, and the result would look like this in the page:

```
var lstUsersAutoComplete = [{ FirstName: "Mary", ... }, {...}];
```

I think the code scanner still might not like this arrangement, but if it did not, that would only be a false positive, as there's no way to inject executable code into properly formed JSON.